# Can't add custom CSS file to specific admin pages

Tags: 8, theming

So I want to add a CSS file to the node create/edit forms. My code is:

```
function general_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, ['node_article_edit_form', 'node_article_form']) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'general/general_library';
  }
}
```

My library file:

```
general_library:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/admin-styles.css: {}
```

And the general folder structure is:

```
general/
├── assets/
│   ├── css/
│        └── admin-styles.css
```

I rebuilt the caches, the modules is enabled and working, but the CSS file never shows up in the HTML.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm, looks all totally correct. What about server-side caching, browser caching or advanced aggregation or something? What happens when you load the lib from `general_preprocess_page(&$variables)` and `$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'general/general_library';`? Does that work? What does your CSS file actually contain?

Comment: Is the module enabled?